# Gradle dependency jars downloaded in a folder with different name

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle, build.gradle, gradlew

I am running a Spring Boot application through a gradle build and I observe that the dependency jars which are downloaded are kept in a subfolder inside the gradle caches folder, which has a different name.

For example, the gradle dependencies are downloaded in:

```
/root/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-gradle-plugin/2.0.5.RELEASE/2c7ddace2abd741a76720a29365d2dcd7633ef77/spring-boot-gradle-plugin-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar
```

However, I don't understand why the hash key (seems like one) is generated as a subfolder and the jar is inside the subfolder.

As a result of this, the dependency is not being found when I try to load it later during gradle build from a local repository. It shows an error message like could not resolve dependency.

Also why is the dependency being downloaded as `org.springframework.boot` and not `org/springframework/boot`? Since during picking up, it is expecting the dependency to be in a location like this.

Any help on how to resolve this will be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: "it is expecting" - what is "it"?

Comment: When I am running gradle build to pick up from my local repository, the gradle build is expecting to find it in the local repository without the hash key.
For eg, it is searching in org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-gradle-plugin/2.0.5.RELEASE/spring-boot-gradle-plugin-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar but is not finding here.

FYI, my build.gradle has repository as 

repository{
    maven{
        url "<another_server_repo_path>"
    }
}
and I have kept the repo in the other server in /var/www/html/<another_server_repo_path>

Comment: I think you will need to show some Grade code. Grade should know how to locate dependencies that it's managing.

Comment: Please look at the modified comment above.

Comment: can you share a minimum example reproducing the problem including the error message you're seing. The gradle cache is an internal format that contains hashes etc. for doing performant and resiliant dependency management. you shouldn't need to tinker with the  _internal_ cache layout.

Comment: Hey. Sorry for the delay. I have taken your suggestion at the moment and changed my setup so that gradle itself picks up the dependencies and uses them. I looked it up and found out that gradle downloads dependencies in this folder structure :
**group_id**: **artifact_id**: **version**: **hash_key**
I just wanted to know how to bypass this **hash_key**